# Select a user that has no post named foobar

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table `user` and a table `post`. It is a N-1 relation, meaning that relation is done through `post.user_id`.

I want to find users without post named "foobar". I tried this :

```sql
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE post.title !="foobar"
```

If one user has one post named foobar, it's not returned, but as soon as there is a postnot named foobar the user is returned.

In sql how do I say "I want the users that have not a single post named foobar".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM `posts` 
    WHERE title = 'foobar'
    AND user_id = u.id
)
```

Comment: You are not linking your `NOT EXISTS` with the proper user

Answer (score 0):

You could left join on posts with the title of foobar and then return all rows for which the title is null (there was no join possible).

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
    LEFT JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
        AND posts.title = "foobar"
WHERE posts.title IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference for these types of queries is to use aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT `users`.*
FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
group by users.user_id
having sum(case when post.title = 'foobar' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Out of curiosity : Why ? Readability is far from optimal. Performance ?